# event listener on an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, events, onload

I am writing a web application which loads different page elements through AJAX calls. I want to be able to trigger an onload event when a certain element from an AJAX call is loaded but all the elements I have are DIV's and are unable to trigger such events. Is there anything I could add into the HTML files to trigger an onload event?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or otherwise provide the code examples you have tried so far?

Comment: *"Is there anything I could add into the HTML files to trigger an onload event?"* Yes, an image, or an iframe, etc, but it's the wrong way to do this. Instead, you should be using the complete success callback of the ajax request(pending on how you are sending the ajax request)

Comment: @E.Maggini I fail to see how a code sample would help this question.

Comment: @kevin-B If we could see what OP has tried so far, it would help in guiding OP towards an answer.

Comment: The only thing that would help would be the code that he used to send the ajax request, which isn't what you asked for...

Comment: actually, yes it is exactly what I asked for.What he has tried so far. For example in his ajax call he could look for values and try some solution from there.

Comment: @KevinB I want an ajax call to be made as soon as the user logs in and the home page is loaded. As I am using AJAX the home page is literally just DIV elements adding on to the index page. I just need an element I can put in so I can call an onload event to trigger the next AJAX call which effectively populates the users specific home page.

Comment: *"I just need an element I can put in..."* No, you don't. The ajax request you are using to log the user in can also be used to send off the next ajax request. Can you show us this ajax request?

Comment: @KevinB this would only populate upon login. not if the user were to navigate away from the home page, and then navigate back.

Comment: Walk us through the process. User visits site, gets home page and a login form. User logs in, and homepage is replaced with new logged in home page. User refreshes, user gets new logged in home page. right?

Comment: @KevinB The user is to login on the login page, upon entering credentials, the home page is loaded with user specific content which is populated by an ajax call to the database. Obviously the home page with the user specific content will need to be on the home page every time they navigate to the home page, thus making it unacceptable to call the function only upon login. I want something that will trigger every time the Home page is called.

Comment: What calls the home page after the user is loggedin and a refresh occurs? another ajax request? or does the server return it directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can listen on `ready()` event (in loaded page) wich runs script after page (or loaded elements) is completly loaded:

Your loaded page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Action to perform when page (or loaded element) is completly loaded
    });
```

It may help you better:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url:"file_to_load.html",
      success:function(result,status,xhr) {
      alert("Ajax request: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      $("#container").html(result);
      }
  });
});
```

The `success` parameter executes a function when the request succeeds.

The parameter you most need is `result` wich contains the data returned from the server.

This will alert *"Ajax request: 200 OK"* and then write the content of ***file_to_load.html*** into `#container`.

References:

- `ready()` - https://api.jquery.com/ready/
- `.ajax()` - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/